# rich autocomplete does not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, autocomplete, richfaces

I am sure I am doing something stupid so I apologize up front.   I cannot get rich:autocomplete to save my life.

I get this error when I load the page "Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (2000) and height (0) cannot be <= 0"

I have seen several posts about this so I checked our web.xml and you can see we have the params everyone has suggested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>Phizzle Platform</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.responsiveDesign</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.clientSideStyle</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
<param-value>-</param-value>
</context-param>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>less</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletInitializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>init.initializer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>

    </multipart-config>

</servlet>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.IllegalStateException</exception-type>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

Here is my bean code which I have verified is returning a list of strings properly

```
public List<String> tagAutoComplete(Object o){
    String searchString = (String) o; 
    List<String> results =    filter(Matchers.containsString(searchString.toUpperCase()), tagSuggestions);
    System.out.println("results:" + results);
    return results;

}
```

Here is my page code

```
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="formbox">
...
   <rich:autocomplete value="#{fanlist.tagInputs}" autocompleteMethod="#      {fanlist.tagAutoComplete}"  mode="ajax" tokens=", " minChars="3" autofill="false" style="width:200px; height:50px;"/>
...

     </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Nothing is returned for the auto complete even though the bean is showing results.  Please help.

Read @Andrey 's comment below.  As you can see I am using the version of Richfaces mentioned in the bug as a fix, so not sure what the issue is?

[image: image of the pom]
[image: bug comment]

Comment: Related post: https://community.jboss.org/thread/234077

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in RichFaces: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11103.
Try updating to the most recent version.

Comment: see my edits above, I think this is something different.

Comment: @sgoldberg It looks more like a bug in RF then. It might be so that the issue is still reproducible when rich:autocomplete is used as in your case.

Comment: we decided to write our own custom component got sick of trying to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me:

```
<a4j:outputPanel><rich:autocomplete value="#{fanlist.tagInputs}" autocompleteMethod="#fanlist.tagAutoComplete}" valueChangeListener="#fanlist.tagValueChanged}" mode="ajax" tokens=", " minChars="3" autofill="false" style="width:200px; height:50px;"><a4j:ajax event="selectitem" /></rich:autocomplete></a4j:outputPanel>
```

And add this mehod to your bean in order to get theselected value:

```
public void tagValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {   
    if (null != event.getNewValue()) {
        System.out.println(" event.getNewValue() "+event.getNewValue());
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override style for autocomplete. Default has url that does not exist.

```
input.rf-au-inp {
    background-image: none;
}
```